# Powershell script to empty a shared folder except from certain ones

Tags: powershell

I'm not too much into powershell expert, though I have to run a script that periodically deletes the content of a windows server shared folder except for some of its subfolders and their content.
Can anyone please help with this?

thanks

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. I suggest you edit your post to include the code you already have tried including details on what it does, how that differs from what you expected as well as error messages, should you get any.

Answer (score 0):

So, based on your statement, you are looking for a script to periodically enumerate the list of files and folders in file share.

You also must make sure that at least *some files are NOT deleted.

You can achieve this with something similar to the code below:

```
#Define your SMB server share (You can always add this as an input paramter to the script if you have multiples or even just create an array that contains all of the shares up to you
$SmbServer = "\\FileServer.Contoso.com\TestShare"

#Connect to the SMB Server share (you probably need creds here for your environment but, #for my test it is not needed
Set-Location $SmbServer

#You need a way of determining which files are not to be deleted, for this test, I have files in a share labeled delete and no.delete, this script will delete the "deletes" and bypass the "no.deletes"
$protectedFileString = "no.delete"

#Get the list of files and folders in the directory
$filesList = Get-ChildItem

#Clear the screen for ease of reading
Clear-Host

    #Delete files and bypass protected files
    foreach($file in $filesList)
    {

        #Find protected files
        if($file.Name -Match $protectedFileString)
        {
        #Notify user that we are skipping a protected file due to a match in $protectedFileString
            Write-Host "Skipping " $file.FullName -ForegroundColor Green
        }
        #Find files to be deleted
        else
        {
        #Notify user we are deleting file due to a NOT match of $protectedFileString
            Write-Host "Deleting" $file.FullName -ForegroundColor Yellow
        }

    }

#Is this list of protected and not-protected files correct?
$correct = Read-Host "`nIs this the correct set of files to protect and delete? (Y/N)"

    #If NO, fix the script to correctly identify the files and folders to protect and delete
    if ($correct -eq "N")
    {
        Write-Host "`nFix the script to correctly identify your list of protected files and folders"
        Set-Location c:\
        return
    }
    #else, delete the non-protected files
    else
    {
        foreach($file in $filesList)
        {
           if($file.Name -NotMatch $protectedFileString)
           {
           Remove-Item $file
           }
        }
        #Set location back to the root of c on local machine
        Set-Location c:\
    }
```

```
Output should be something like this:
Deleting \\FileServer.Contoso.com\TestShare\delete
Skipping  \\FileServer.Contoso.com\TestShare\no.delete
Deleting \\FileServer.Contoso.comTestShare\delete.txt
Skipping  \\FileServer.Contoso.com\TestShare\no.delete.txt

Is this the correct set of files to protect and delete? (Y/N): Y

Deleting file:  \\FileServer.Contoso.com\TestShare\delete

Deleting file:  \\FileServer.Contoso.com\TestShare\delete.txt

PS C:\>
```